# Why do get_category_by_slug() crashes WordPress 4.8

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to hide "uncategorized" from the list of selectable post categories and  wrote some code to achieve that. **This function worked fine** up to WP 4.7.5, the categories were successfully hidden:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'myproject_hide_uncategorized',1);
function myproject_hide_uncategorized( $exclude_query ) {
  if (function_exists('get_current_screen')) {
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();

    if ($currentScreen->base == 'post') {
      $newquery = "";
      $excluidos = array();
      $excluidos[] = get_category_by_slug('sem-categoria')->cat_ID;
      $excluidos[] = get_category_by_slug('uncategorized')->cat_ID;
      foreach ($excluidos as $excluido) {
        $newquery .= " AND t.term_id <> '$excluido' ";
      }
      $exclude_query .= $newquery;
    }
  }
  return $exclude_query;
}
```

However, on later versions (4.8.1 being the latest so far), whenever I try to edit a post or create a new one (visiting `localhost/wp-admin/post-new.php"),  I get the following error message shown:

> `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php on line 294`

Raising the memory limit just gets me a timeout error. I am able to replicate the behavior in clean installs of both WP 4.8 and 4.8.1

It looks like the crash is caused by these four lines, adding it to the `functions.php` file of any theme seems to cause a crash:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'this_will_crash_wordpress');
function this_will_crash_wordpress( $exclude_query ) {
  get_category_by_slug('uncategorized');
}
```

**What changed between 4.7.5 that causes this error? How can I make it go away? Do I have to rewrite my code? If so, *how*?**

Answer (score -1):

try to use get_term_by(); https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

like this

```
get_term_by('slug', 'uncategorized', 'category');
```

Comment: Raising the memory limit just gets me a timeout error.

Comment: try to use get_term_by();